# remove exe privileges requirement

Tags: elevated

Epic Games Launcher requires administrator (elevated) privileges to run games such as GTA V.

I don't want to give my son those privileges, and I don't want to always be around to start the game.

The executable that gets run resides at `C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\Redistributables\Rockstar-Games-Epic.exe`.

What I have done is to change ownership of `C:\Program Files\Epic Games` and everything inside it to the `users` user group. And have have given that user group Full Control of that folder and everything inside of it.

However, the executable's icon still has the yellow/blue shield shown over it. And it still requires the extra privileges to start running.

[image: Rockstar-Games-Epic.exe]

I know how to get the shield there for an application by using Troubleshooter For Compatibility, then stating the executable needs admin privileges, and then Windows would alter the executable to make it require admin privileges. ... But now I need to do the exact opposite and remove the administrator requirement from the executable.

How do I do this?

(I know the changing of ownership and security settings might not be enough, and that the executable might be instable if I get it to run without admin privileges. But I just want to see it run wihtout admin privileges first.)

Comment: The compatibility troubleshooter does not alter the executable. // Programs can indicate they need elevation in their embedded manifest. This is not related to file permissions at all. You won’t be able to get rid of it. You cannot change it without invalidating the digital signature.

Comment: I’m not quite following. What is the embedded manifest and why is it not (part of) the executable. Is it saved somewhere else than in the file? And why would it be possible to add the indication to the manifest, but not possible to remove such an indication, given digital signatures?

Comment: [Win32 embedded manifests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) are inside the `.exe` file. The keyword (not documented here) is `requestedExecutionLevel`. // The compatibility troubleshooter saves its changes to the registry (keyword `AppCompatFlags`). It can only be used to _add_ privileges.

Comment: @John You just assumed I down voted something?! And then you down vote me for no reason?!

Comment: I downvoted because mucking with permissions and flags will NOT permit a proper EXE to run under a standard user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this software, which should Run application as different user or start program as administrator from a standard account like the runas command, but including password and encryption.

https://www.robotronic.de/runasspcen.html